# Compute two-dimensional integral over a region bounded by circular arcs

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

How to compute
$$
\iint_{M}y\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y
$$
where $
\ M\equiv\left\{\,%
\left(\, x,y\,\right)\ \mid\ y\ \geq\ 0\,,\quad x^{2} + y^{2}\ \leq\ 1\,,\quad
\left(\, x - 1\,\right)^{2} + y^{2}\ \geq\ 1
\,\right\}?
$

> My guess was that
>   $\displaystyle{\quad%
> -1\ \leq x\ \leq\ 1\,,\quad\,\sqrt{\, 1 - x^{2}\,}\,\ \leq\ y\ \leq
> \,\sqrt{\, 1 -\left(\, x - 1\,\right)^{2}\,}\,,\quad}$ then integrate
>   $y\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y$ using these intervals, but answer wasn't even near the right one.

Comment: You have the intersection of two circles.  One centred at the origin, one centred at (1,0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to make it an iterated integral:
$\int_0^1 (\int_{\phi(x)}^{\psi(x)} y dy) dx$.

What are $\phi(x)$ and $\psi(x)$? Lets check the shape of the domain:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D1+and+%28x-1%29%5E2+%2B+y%5E2%3D1 (the intersection of the circles for $y \geq 0$). So we can split at $x=1/2$ into two integrals with nice bounds:

$\int_0^{1/2} (\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}} y dy) dx + \int_{1/2}^1 (\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} y dy) dx$. The rest of the exercise is just integration of polynomials -- you should try doing it by yourself. You can also try iterating the other way -- first integrate by $dx$ and then by $dy$.

Comment: Why is it in the form you wrote and not in $\int_{0}^1 \int_{\sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}ydxdy$?

Comment: 1) You have the $dxdy$ in wrong order (you cannot integrate by $dx$ and have the limits dependent on $x$); 2) you should look at it this way: for given $x$, what are the $y$'s that are in $M$? Find lower and upper limit and these are your inner integral's limits.

Answer (score 1):

HINT

I would say,

$\displaystyle \int\int_My\,dx\,dy=\int_{-1}^{1/2}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}y\,dy\,dx-\int_{0}^{1/2}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}}y\,dy\,dx=\cdots$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
You can use *cylindrical coordinates*:
$\ds{\quad x\ =\ r\cos\pars{\phi}\,,\quad y=r\sin\pars{\phi}\quad}$ with
$\ds{\quad r\ >\ 0\,,\quad 0\ \leq\ \phi\ <\ 2\pi\quad}$ such that:

> \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\iint_{M}y\,\dd x\,\dd y}
> =\left.\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi}r\sin\pars{\phi}r\,\dd r\,\dd\phi\,
> \right\vert_{0\ <\ r\ <\ 1\atop
> {r\sin\pars{\phi}\ >\ 0 \atop -2r\cos\pars{\phi} + 1\ \geq\ 0}}
> \\[5mm]&=\left.\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2\pi}r\sin\pars{\phi}r\,\dd r\,\dd\phi\,
> \right\vert_{\sin\pars{\phi}\ >\ 0\atop r\ \leq\ \sec\pars{\phi}/2}
> =\left.\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin\pars{\phi}\int_{0}^{1}r^{2}\,\dd r\,\dd\phi\,
> \right\vert_{\, r\ \leq\ \sec\pars{\phi}/2}
> \\[5mm]&=\int_{0}^{\pi/3}\sin\pars{\phi}
> \int_{0}^{\sec\pars{\phi}/2}r^{2}\,\dd r\,\dd\phi
> +\int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2}\sin\pars{\phi}\int_{0}^{1}r^{2}\,\dd r\,\dd\phi
> \\[5mm]&={1 \over 24}\int_{0}^{\pi/3}
> {\sin\pars{\phi} \over \cos^{3}\pars{\phi}}\,\dd\phi
> +{1 \over 3}\int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2}\sin\pars{\phi}\,\dd\phi
> =\left.{1 \over 48}\,{1 \over \cos^{2}\pars{\phi}}\right\vert_{\, 0}^{\, \pi/3}
> -\left.{1 \over 3}\,\cos\pars{\phi}\right\vert_{\,\pi/3}^{\,\pi/2}
> \\[5mm]&={1 \over 48}\pars{4 - 1} - {1 \over 3}\,\pars{0 - \half} = \color{#66f}{\Large{11 \over 48}}
> \end{align}